# subaru impreza 1998 clutch noise

Tags: transmission, clutch, noise, subaru

I have subaru impreza 1998 with manual transmission.  When I push the clutch I hear a noise like the noise of the power steering belt when its over tightened.  The mechanic replaced the clutch bearing [ throw out bearing] . But the noise didn't go. Today he told me that the transmission needs replacement!  I dont hear any noise while driving except something like wennnnnn when am on fist and second gears.
What to do ! 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symptoms of a bad throwout bearing are (usually) noise with the clutch disengaged, which goes away when the clutch is pressed in. You were getting the exact opposite, which indicates that you're suffering input shaft wear, which is common on 5MT Subaru transmissions.

With input shaft wear, the shaft gets a little bit smaller over time, but the throw-out bearings remain the same size. That gives more (too much) wiggle room, so that you're now pressing slightly off-centre on the pressure plate diaphragm. Eventually this will start giving you transmission shuddering.

Assuming (because I'm making a lot of assumptions based on little information) that the above is true, you're looking at a new transmission (which will fix the whine, at a cost of more than the car is worth), or you may try a PDM Snout Repair kit; it's an oversized throwout bearing, plus a sleeve to fit on the input shaft. Cost is about $150, plus installation. Have a look at http://www.pdmusa.com/.

Comment: Thanks Pete , but correct me if am wrong.  Throwout bearing will spin when the clutch pedal is pressed.  Then it will be in contact with the spring diaghram thatis rotating with the flywheel. Otherwise it will be idle when the clutch is released.  The car drivers like normal without any significant noise. But when pressing the clutch ;specially when the car is moving slowly or stopped;  this weird noise will show up.  Its  rotating noise proportional to the engine rpm. When the rpm gets high the noise will disappear!  I